# Undefined behaviour in Json

Tags: json, json.net

What **should** happen when the value of a property is set to undefined in a json string. 
i.e:

```
{"Name":undefined}
```

The following example is using the json.net library.  An exception is thrown when de-serializing the object.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SimpleObject>("{\"Name\":undefined}");

public class SimpleObject
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException was unhandled
  Message=Error reading string. Unexpected token: Undefined. Path 'Value', line 1, position 18.
  Source=Newtonsoft.Json
  LineNumber=1
  LinePosition=18
  Path=Value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is fine.

Jsonlint.org throws an error too.

And reading the documentation on json.org the "value" element may have the following variants:

string
number
object
array
true
false
null

As you can see, undefined is NOT listed. Object does also not count as undefined.