# How to add "undefined" to a JObject collection - where is JToken/JValue.Undefined?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, undefined, linq-to-json

When using Json.NET, I am trying to create a JSON structure dynamically using the ["JSON to LINQ"](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html) support.

In the following, `jObject` is a [JObject](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) and JObject.Add takes (string, [JToken](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm)). However, I cannot find out how to add either an Undefined or a Null token - nor can I find out how to create JValues with the appropriate Null/Undefined type.

```
string value = GetValue();
if (value == "undefined") {
  jObject.Add(key, /* how to add "Undefined" token? */);
} else if (value == "null") {
  jObject.Add(key, /* how to add "Null" token? */);
} else {
  jObject.Add(key, new JToken(value));  /* String value/token */
}
```

How do I explicitly add a JToken/JValue for a JSON Undefined? How about for a JSON Null?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Setting a property to **undefined** is functionally equivalent to not setting the property at all. So, if the property is undefined, you just don't add any properties to your `JObject`. (And this is probably the reason why `undefined` isn't supported by JSON — it's completely redundant.)

**Null** is represented by `new JValue((object)null)`, if I remember correctly.

P.S. With your code, you won't be able to tell the difference between a string `"undefined"` and an `undefined` value, as well as between `"null"` and `null`. You probably need to rethink your design.

Comment: Oh, my apologizes: `undefined` is *not* valid JSON. This is *the* point, not a secondary point of "functionally equivalent". It simply is invalid in context (probably preserved for read-*in* compatibility) and my assumptions were wrong. Using `new JValue((object)null))` works as I expect here - to emit a `null`, naturally.

Comment: As @Rohit says, JValue has methods for create special values, such as JValue.CreateUndefined() and JValue.CreateNull()

Answer (score 3):

```
jObject.Add(key, /* how to add "Undefined" token? */);

jObject.Add(key,JValue.CreateUndefined());
```

Comment: It looks like it is an alias for the most part: "CreateUndefined(): Creates a JValue *null* value." I wonder if there is a difference/use-case for such, going back my incorrect assumption that undefined values were allowed in JSON. The corresponding CreateNull() method answers the other question well.

Comment: there is a different JTokenType, so unlikely is same thing. https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JValue.cs

Answer (score 2):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455675/undefined-behaviour-in-json), it doesn't support `undefined`.

After searching the docs, I found 2 references to "Undefined", but no explanation on how they might be used:

- [JsonConvert Fields](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/Fields_T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm)
- [JTokenWriter.WriteUndefined Method](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JTokenWriter_WriteUndefined.htm)

Comment: I suspect that they can't be used properly. The only way to use that is to use a custom `JsonConverter` and call `WriteUndefined` in `WriteJson`. Useless for `JObject` construction and reading JSON.

Comment: (Thanks for the linked post. I read "..undefined is NOT listed. Object does also not count as undefined" and slapped my head.)