# Partial deserialization with Json.net

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

Is there an existing way with Json.net to deserialize a json string into an anonymous object (which has the json properties only) using a concrete type as template ?

**Exemple**

JSON:

```
{ X: 1, Z: 2 }
```

Model:

```
public class Point {
    public float X { get; set; }
    public float Y { get; set; }
    public float Z { get; set; }
}
```

Desired deserialized **ouput** anonymous object :

```
new { X=1.0f, Z=1.0f } //Please note that X & Z are typed according to the Point class.
```

I want to do something like :

```
var @object = serializer.DeserializeAsAnonymous<Point>(json);
```

Why? I want to detect which properties of the model to update using reflection on both sides (model and provided deserialized json).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serializer.Populate` is the method I was looking for...
It doesn't produce an anonymous object, but it populates an existing object with the existing json properties.

Answer (score 3):

```
var point = new { X = 0.0f, Z = 0.0f };
var jsonResponse = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, point);
```

Comment: Thanks for tour answer, but this is not what I am looking for. I want to use an existing type as template and deserialize the json provided properties into an anonymous object. **Please, do not vote up.**

Comment: @fso the answer does exactly what you are asking. Can you please clarify how this does not answer your question and we can see if we can address that.

Comment: _the answer does exactly what you are asking_ --> NO
1) I do not want to instanciate an anonymous type before deserialization.
2) The _template_ type used for deserialization should be **static** and should be used as a _mask_  and for the properties type validation.

Comment: @fso You only need to instantiate the anonymous type so it can be used as a template; anonymous types have no class so it needs this to be used as a type. There is no other way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, there is no way to do this unless you use code generation.  Anonymous types are defined at *compile time*, whereas you are saying you don't know what properties you want in the anonymous type until you get the JSON (at *run time*).

If you're just trying to detect which properties were present in the JSON or not, you could deserialize into a `JObject` and then process that to figure out what changed.  Alternatively, you could add a status dictionary to your model and then deserialize to it using a `JsonConverter`.  See [Is there a way in Json.NET serialization to distinguish between "null because not present" and "null because null"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29024284/10263) for examples of these ideas.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to know if I need to write my own converter with or without some expression magic, this is not part of the Json.net library so I will implement it myself. PS: ty for the link.