# How to ignore null values on serialization but include them on deserialization

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net

### Summary

Is it possible to use `Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore` for output (serialization) but use `NullValueHandling.Include` for input (deserialization)?

---

### Details

I'm building a JSON API using ASP.NET Web API. I want to remove unnecessary null values from the output which is easy to do with the following code:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings =
    new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings {
        NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore
    };
```

However, on input, I want to use `NullValueHandling.Include` to include null values and have that trigger property setters on my model objects.

### Why?

These property setters look like the following:

```
public long? Foo
{
    get { return _Foo; }
    set { _Foo = MarkApplied(nameof(Foo), value); }
}
```

where `MarkApplied` remembers that the `Foo` property was explicity set. This allows me to tell the difference between an input JSON object of:

```
{ Foo: 123, Bar: "bar" }
```

which intends for me to update the `Foo` property to `123` and the `Bar` property to `"bar"`,

```
{ Foo: null, Bar: "bar" }
```

which intends for me to update the `Foo` property to `null` and the `Bar` property to `"bar"`, and

```
{ Bar: "bar" }
```

which intends for me to update the `Bar` property to `"bar"` and not change anything about the `Foo` property (as opposed to setting it to `null`).

### What won't work

I've already looked at [`DefaultValueHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm) as an option. For one, I really only want this behavior for null values, not for numerics and booleans which have meaningful default values. Also, `Include` and `Ignore` seems to pretty much match the behavior of `NullValueHandling`, and the `Populate` and `IgnoreAndPopulate` options aren't what I want, because they would trigger the property setters even when the property isn't included in the input JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29024284/is-there-a-way-in-json-net-serialization-to-distinguish-between-null-because-no?rq=1), and was able to create a custom JsonConverter that gets the job done:

```
    public class V2JsonConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ApiModelBase));
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var jsonObj = JObject.Load(reader);
            var targetObj = (ApiModelBase)Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);

            foreach (var prop in objectType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanWrite))
            {
                JToken value;
                if (jsonObj.TryGetValue(prop.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase, out value))
                {
                    prop.SetValue(targetObj, value.ToObject(prop.PropertyType, serializer));
                }
            }

            return targetObj;
        }

        public override bool CanWrite => false;

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```